# An algorithm to compute sine and cosine within $n$-digit precision

Tags: approximation-algorithms

I know CORDIC, but is there a better algorithm to compute $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ within specified $n$-digit accuracy?

Comment: This [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19946/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-computing-sinx-to-t-bits-of-precision) from mathoverflow seems relevant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Elementary_functions

Comment: [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) / wikipedia aka digit-by-digit or Volders algorithm